# SQL - Query to sum values after a certain value for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having some trouble with a query. I would like to sum values that appears after the last value in a different column, for each ID.

The database looks like this but without the notes next to the count values:

ID_____Date______Amount_____Count

8____2016-04-20____300________500 *(Since last count)*

8____2016-04-21____100________100 *(Since last count, only 100 from this line)*

8____2016-04-22____200________0

8____2016-04-23____300________0

8____2016-04-24____400________900 *(Since last count: 400+300+200)*

8____2016-04-25____**300**________0

112__2016-04-20____100________0

112__2016-04-21____100________500 *(Since last count)*

112__2016-04-22____**200**________0

112__2016-04-23____**200**________0

112__2016-04-24____**200**________0

112__2016-04-25____**400**________0

333__2016-04-20____700________1000 *(Since last count)*

333__2016-04-21____400________0

333__2016-04-22____200________0

333__2016-04-23____200________0

333__2016-04-24____200________0

333__2016-04-25____400________1400 *(Since last count, 400+200+200+200+400)

I would like to sum the **bold** values since they have not been added to count yet. No values from ID 333 since they have a count on the last row.

The result of the query should be **1300** (400+200+200+200+300)

There is about 150 different IDs in the real database

Would appreciate your help :)

Comment: 400 + 300 + 200 <> 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this is a bad database design. You're keeping duplicate data in your database (these summed amounts are already in the database, you just need to calculate them), which is going to just cause you even further headaches down the road. Get rid of that column and get rid of this problem entirely.

That said, this should give you what you need:

```
;WITH CTE_MaxDates AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        MAX([date]) AS max_date
    FROM
        My_Table
    WHERE
        [count] > 0
    GROUP BY
        id
)
SELECT
    MT.id,
    SUM(MT.amount)
FROM
    My_Table MT
INNER JOIN CTE_MaxDates MD ON
    MD.id = MT.id AND
    MD.max_date < MT.[date]
GROUP BY
    MT.id
```

Also, if those are actual column names, then "date" and "count" make for bad column names as they are reserved words in SQL Server and they aren't very descriptive either.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer, it worked great! And to explain the database. The amount and count is not always the same. The count is the actual amount when counted by hand. "Amount" is what the system thinks it is. They are  not called "date" and "count" in the real database, so there is no issue there :) Again, thanks a lot Tom!